# Link not working due to position absolute and z index

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index, styling

I am currently trying to get the link on this page: https://streamlineas.com/ to work. It is the button on the top right that says "Request a Demo" but it only doesn't work on the screen size smaller than 1070px (I believe this specific button only shows on screen sizes less than 1070px). I think it has something to do with the z index not working with the link. I tried switching it to position relative and it still seemed to not work for me. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Why not create the a tag outside the list intead? People with get the wrong impresion of it being a button while it is actually a navbar list item instead. You can click the white space above and below the button. Also, notice that in mobile, your button is outside the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link works fine if you turn javascript off. So the css is not the problem, there is an event attached somewhere that is stopping the link working.

Do you have access to the html? In the first instance try removing  `data-toggle="modal" data-target=".form-modal"` from the link in question.